# Turn semitransparent PNG image into a white silhouette, preserving transparency

Tags: gimp, transparency

I have an PNG image like this with a transparent background:

[image: Sample Image]

How can I change the image color to white, and keep the transparent background in GIMP?

The desired result is a white silhouette on a transparent background.

Comment: @Scott I zoomed in the picture and using bucket fill tool, I put white color manually for each component. But this is becoming tedious for every images. Is there a better way than this ?

Comment: To "completely modify the existing colors to white", you slect all, and hit delete. Can you clarify what you *really* want? Do you want to convert the image to greyscale (also known as "black & white")? Do you want to make the transparent area(s) not transparent?

Comment: @horatio, I want the non-transparent areas to be converted to white.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several quick ways to reduce an image to transparent white tones. From the *Colors* menu select one of these

- **Threshold...:** slide black (left side) to `0`.
- **Colorize...:** slide *Lightness* to `100`.
- **Curves...:** slide black (left) to the top (white).
- **Bucket Fill White:** Fill mode *Lighten Only* or *Addition*.

Any of these procedures will lead to the following transparent white image:

[image]

Note that due to the transparency a colored background will shine through your image.

Answer (score 4):

Other ways to do this:

- Open the **Channels dialog** and de-select the alpha channel.  Then use Bucket Fill in "Fill whole selection" mode.

or:

- Use Layer → Mask → **Add Layer Mask...** and select "Transfer layer's alpha channel".  Then use Bucket Fill as above on the content of the layer (*not* on the mask).

Answer (score 3):

So you need to select the layer contents to change it's color:

> Right-click on the layer and select **Alpha to selection**
>
> Or go to: **Layers > Transperency > Alpha to Selection**
>
> Then fill with white using the `Bucket Fill`.

## Reference:

[Alpha to Selection](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-layer-alpha-selection-replace.html)
[Bucket Fill](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-bucket-fill.html)

Comment: This converts transparent area to White. I want the inverse.

Comment: So you want the image (screwdriver) to be white?

Comment: Yes, I want the screwdriver to be white.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly